# Exception running powershell script from MSBuild Exec Task

Tags: powershell, msbuild, cmd

i´m having a problem with MSBuild and Powershell. There is a PS-script that i want to execute within the MSBuild exec-Task.

The Problem: Running the Script direct from CMD works, but running the script within MSBuild I get an error.

Here the MSBuild script:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

<PropertyGroup>  
    <PathToSvnClient>C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet\Subversion Client</PathToSvnClient>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <!-- set Folder to Svn Repository for svn info command-->
    <SvnFolder Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\.."/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="SvnInfo">
    <!-- get SVN Revision and Repository Path -->
    <SvnInfo LocalPath="%(SvnFolder.FullPath)" ToolPath="$(PathToSvnClient)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="Revision" />
        <Output TaskParameter="RepositoryPath" PropertyName="RepositoryPath" />
    </SvnInfo>
</Target>

<Target Name="SetProductVersion" DependsOnTargets="SvnInfo">
    <Exec Command="powershell -file &quot;Scripts\SetSth.ps1&quot; -PARAM &quot;$(PathToSth)&quot; -SVNID $(Revision) -SVNFOLDER &quot;$(RepositoryPath)&quot;" LogStandardErrorAsError="true" ContinueOnError="false"/>
</Target>
```

The Command is executed exactly the same way as on CMD, but i get an exception from the Powershell Script for the SVNFOLDER param.

The Command that is executed looks like this:

```
powershell -file "Scripts\SetSth.ps1" -PARAM "C:\abc\cde" -SVNID 1234
-SVNFOLDER "https://domain/svn/rep/branches/xy%20(Build%2012)"
```

So from CMD it works, from within MSBuild not. I have no idea why. I hope you got an idea.

Answer (score 4):

What about this approach playing with double and singles quotes:

```
<Target Name="SetProductVersion" DependsOnTargets="SvnInfo">
    <Exec Command="powershell -command &quot;&amp; {Scripts\SetSth.ps1 -PARAM '$(PathToSth)' -SVNID '$(Revision)' -SVNFOLDER '$(RepositoryPath)'}&quot;" LogStandardErrorAsError="true" ContinueOnError="false"/>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Double check your paths.

Remember, powershell invoked in this way runs as Msbuild.exe under whatever user is executing the build.  To msbuild.exe, a straight call to cmd.exe is going to start in the working directory where msbuild lives.

Assume `-file "Scripts\SetSth.ps1"` references **C:\users\yourusername\Scripts\SetSth.ps1**

So for you, calling cmd.exe and running that may work just fine, b/c your working directory is going to match ***C:\users\yourusername***

For msbuild.exe, its likely unable to find that file, as its starting in something like ****C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0****

So it's looking for **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0\Scripts\SetSth.ps1**

I would try making that file path fully qualified.  If that still doesn't work, have cmd.exe dump its results into a property and have msbuild log it.  Then you can review the paths.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the script gets started and then raises an exception. So it has be sth. else. Currently i´m looking at the "%20" of the SVNFOLDER Path. I assume that MSBuild trys to substitute it with an item?!

Comment: It shouldn't, msbuild uses %% syntax just like any xml-based system to parse special characters.  What you may wanna try is building your command string in a Property, then outputing that property in the log and see if it matches what you expect

Comment: It´s strange. If i run the MSBuild script it´s writing the target name and the command "powershell -file "Scripts\SetSth.ps1" -PARAM "C:\abc\cde" -SVNID 1234
-SVNFOLDER "https://domain/svn/rep/branches/xy%20(Build%2012)"" but powershell gets "powershell -file "Scripts\SetSth.ps1" -PARAM "C:\abc\cde" -SVNID 1234
-SVNFOLDER "https://domain/svn/rep/branches/xy0(Build012)"" so the "%20" is substituted with "0" and that is not what i expect in the script. (i do a match and replace in there). The question now is, why tells me MSBuild that it uses the "%20" and not "0"??

Comment: What are you using the "0" for?  If its just to trigger a find replace, can you use something that isn't an ASCII short code?  MSBUILD is XML so %20 is a valid code, vs just some string.  You'd prob need to use [[CDATA to pass it untouched ... but if you're just looking to trigger a "hey, substitute here", can you use something else like --**-- ?